# insert into Hashtable<Character, List<Boolean>>

Tags: java

I am not sure why I am getting the error under my `put`:

```
The method put(Character, List<Boolean>) in the type 
Hashtable<Character,List<Boolean>> is not applicable for the arguments (char, boolean)
```

I think I have all the matching types

Here is my code

```
    Hashtable<Character, List<Boolean>> charCheck =
         new Hashtable<Character, List<Boolean>>();
    List<Boolean> used = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    //Set<String> nonDuplicate = new Set<String>();
    // make a hashtable of characters used
    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray(); 
    for (char c : charArray) {
        charCheck.put(c, used.add(false));
```

Comment: Your `Hashtable` values are meant to be `List<Boolean>`, but you are trying to put a `used.add(false)` which returns the previous value stored which would be of type `Boolean`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Correction: `add` returns a `boolean`, not a `Boolean`, and regardless of the type of the list: it's an indication of whether the list changed.

Comment: BTW, why are you using `Hashtable`s and not `HashMap`s?

Comment: @MarkPeters Yeah, my bad. I was thinking of `put`.

Comment: I suspect you don't actually want a `Map<Character, List<Boolean>>`, but rather a `Map<Character, Boolean>`, and by extension, a `Set<Character>`.  Ask yourself, what does the **list** of booleans mapped to `'a'` represent?  Or should `'a'` be mapped to a single true/false value?  But in general, if you do want a `Map<K, List<V>>`, you're almost always better off using a [`ListMultimap<K, V>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) from Guava, which models this directly and handles the initial (empty) case for you.

Comment: Hashtable? why not hash map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List#add` method in Java returns a `boolean` indication of whether the value ws successfully added to the `List` or not.
You should separate adding a new `List` to your `Map` from adding a new element to it:

```
Hashtable<Character, List<Boolean>> charCheck = new Hashtable<Character, List<Boolean>>();
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray(); 

for (char c : charArray) {
    List<Boolean> used = charCheck.get(c);

    // If the char isn't in the map yet, add a new list
    if (used == null) {
        used = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        charCheck.put (c, used);
    }

    used.add(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to treat each `ArrayList` separately, i.e. have one `ArrayList` per `Character` key.

```
List<Boolean> used;

char[] charArray = str.toCharArray(); 

for (char c : charArray) {

    used = charCheck.get(c); // Get the list of values for this character

    if (used == null) { // No values stored so far for this character
        used = new ArrayList<Boolean>(); // Create a new (empty) list of values
        charCheck.put(c, used); // Add the empty list of values to the map
    }

    used.add(false); // Add the value for this character to the value list
}
```

Also, I would suggest using a `HashMap` instead of a `Hashtable`:

```
HashMap<Character, List<Boolean>> charCheck = new HashMap<Character, List<Boolean>>();
```

Comment: Is there a reason hashmap is used over hashtable? Ive read that the only difference is a bit of performance because a hashtable is thread safe.

Comment: Yes, but that is a significant difference. Hashtable comes from the early days of Java, so it is nit used much anymore. The HashMap implementation is more efficient, too. In other words: use a HashMap. :-)